# ul wont center despite same cs properties as img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pug

https://codepen.io/saintnicks78/pen/BRgYbg
The image is centered properly using same properties as .centered (here using .fade for it) but the ul  element is more to the right even though top and left are set to 50% using .centered

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px; left: 200px; /*for example purposes only*/
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;



}
li {

    position: absolute;
    color:white;

    font-size: -rem(10px);
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    color: rgba(223,190,106,0.7);
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(223,190,106,0.8), rgba(146,111,52,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-position: 1% 50%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin: -rem(10px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(223,190,106,0.3);
    padding: 5px 5px 5px;



    display:none;

  }

.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;

  }
```

html/jade:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
h1.left My
  h1.
  body(style='background-color:black')
  p
    a.fade(href="#")
     img.fade(src='http://data.whicdn.com/images/18140107/large.jpg', 
 height='150', width='200')

  p 
    ul.centered
      li.none
      li Chapter 1 
      li Chapter 2
      li Chapter 3
      li Chapter 4
      li Chapter 5
      li Chapter 6
      li Chapter 7
      li Chapter 8
      li Chapter 9
      li Chapter 10
```

js:

```
var type = 1, //circle type - 1 whole, 0.5 half, 0.25 quarter
    radius = '22em', //distance from center
    start = -90, //shift start from 0
    $elements = $('li:not(:first-child)'),
    numberOfElements = (type === 1) ?  $elements.length : $elements.length - 1, //adj for even distro of elements when not full circle
    slice = 360 * type / numberOfElements;

$elements.each(function(i) {
    var $self = $(this),
        rotate = slice * i + start,
        rotateReverse = rotate * -1;

    $self.css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg) translate(' + radius + ') rotate(' + rotateReverse + 'deg)'
    });


});



$('.fade').on('click', function() {
   $('.centered li').each(function(i){
        $(this).delay(500 * i).fadeIn(1500)




      })
  })
```

Comment: déjà vu.. didn't you post this yesterday?

Comment: @ovokuro no, s/he'll post it tomorrow...

Comment: they are in middle (over the image)

Comment: @alivetodie click the sexy lips. they clearly are not.

Comment: @ovokuro you had a dream about me? ah i feel honored.

Comment: margin: -rem(10px); is invalid

Comment: @kappaflow Your pen was created 6 days ago. I'm not going mad :)

Comment: your image is like that. if anyhow you can do that also you will get a black spot in your circle upper half

Comment: @AlivetoDie What yo on about boy?! The li elements are closer to the right of the screen. the image is perfectly centered. I want the li elements to be also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image has transform:

```
translate(-50%, -50%);
```

which puts the top/left co-ordinates in the centre rather than using the top left of the image.

The `<li>`s do not have this so are being positioned based on their top-left corner (if they were taller you'd also see that they are vertically out-of-line/off-centre as well as horizontally).

The js `$self.css` transform is overwriting the css, so must also be applied, but specifically *after* the positioning around the circle:

```
$self.css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)' + 
                 ' translate(' + radius + ')' +
                 ' rotate(' + rotateReverse + 'deg)' + 
                 ' translate(-50%, -50%)'
});
```

Add this to your codepen and it will appear as expected.

Comment: lol, was too focused on the css to notice this little blind spot. thank you sir made my day!